# Matlab error: Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, function, input, arguments

This is the coding of IMDCT. I have no idea on what is going wrong in the following matlab code. The error is not enough input arguments in the following line:

```
if blocksplit_flag(iter) && block_type(iter) == 2;
```

Below is part of the complete coding:

```
function output_data = IMDCT( input_data, block_type, blocksplit_flag, switch_point)   
global sin_window_0 sin_window_1 sin_window_2 sin_window_3;
output_data(1:4,1:576) = double(0);
output_holder(1:36) = double(0);
output_holder_1(1:36) = double(0);
output_holder_2(1:36) = double(0);
output_holder_3(1:36) = double(0);
block_type2_sum(1:3,1:12) = 0;
block_type2_sum_1(1:3,1:12) = 0;
block_type2_sum_2(1:3,1:12) = 0;
block_type2_sum_3(1:3,1:12) = 0;
persistent overlap_adder skipper;
if isempty(overlap_adder)
   overlap_adder = zeros(2,576);
   skipper = zeros(1,18);
end
for iter = 1:4
%decide channel to use the appropriate overlap_adder
if mod(iter,2) == 1;
  channel = 1;
else
  channel = 2;
end    
if blocksplit_flag(iter) && block_type(iter) == 2;
    current_start = 1;
    current_start_2 = 2;
    current_start_3 = 3;
    if switch_point(iter)
        %do long transform for first 2 sub_bands.
        while (current_start <= 36 && current_start_2 <= 36 && current_start_3 <= 36)
            output_holder(:) = 0;
            output_holder_1(:) = 0;
            output_holder_2(:) = 0;
            output_holder_3(:) = 0;

            temp_data = input_data(iter, current_start:current_start+17);
            temp_data_1 = input_data(iter, current_start);
            temp_data_2 = input_data(iter, current_start_2:current_start_2+16);
            temp_data_3 = input_data(iter, current_start_3:current_start_3+15); 
            if temp_data == skipper
            else
                for i = 1:36
                    k1 = (current_start_2:current_start_2+16);
                    k2 = (current_start_3:current_start_3+15);

                    %output_holder(i) = ((temp_data_1 .* cos_imdct_long_1(i,:))+ ((cos_imdct_long_2(i,:)) .*sum((temp_data_2) .* (sin((k1)*((pi/72)*(2i+19))))))+ ((cos_imdct_long_3(i,:)) .* ((temp_data_3).*(sin((k2-2)*((pi/72)*(2i+19)))))))/(sin((pi/72)*(2i+19)));   
                    output_holder_1(i) = (temp_data_1 .* (cos((pi/72).*(2i+19))));
                    output_holder_2(i) = ((cos(3.*((pi/72).*(2i+19)))) .* sum((temp_data_2).*(sin((k1).*((pi/72).*(2i+19))))));
                    output_holder_3(i) = ((cos((pi/72).*(2i+19))) .*sum((temp_data_3).*(sin((k2-2).*((pi/72).*(2i+19))))));

                    output_holder(i) = output_holder_1(i) + output_holder_2(i) + output_holder_3(i);
                end
.
.
.
```

Comment: You have defined `blocksplit_flag` and/or `block_type` as a function. Use [`which`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/which.html) and [the debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to figure out which one. See also: [mcve] and provide a *functional* example and the actual error message.

Comment: If you want them to both equal 2, you must write `if blocksplit_flag(iter) == 2 && block_type(iter) == 2`

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a function and hit the run button before calling the function with declared arguments i.e `(input_data, block_type, blocksplit_flag, switch_point)` as arguments, you will encounter such errors. Calling a function with proper inputs should solve the problem.